# What do Steam OS "minimum system requirements" guarantee in terms of playability?

Tags: steam, system-requirements

I want to buy a game on Steam and my device meets the minimum system requirements.

Am I guaranteed that the game will be playable?

Comment: I'm happily playing BG3 on the lowest spec macbook air m1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *minimum system requirements* is literally the **specifications that your computer must meet in order to run a specific game in the lowest configuration**.

But, *where do these specifications come from?* Well, they are **tested by the company who made the game or independent companies hired to do it**.

*Are they accurate?* Most of the time, yes, **but not always**.

**I recommend that you search for videos or posts** from someone who has tested the game with specifications similar to yours. I particularly like [Technical City](https://technical.city/en/can-i-run-it) to do it.

However, if you buy a game that don't run acceptably in your PC, you can [request a refund](https://store.steampowered.com/steam_refunds/).

But you **can only request a refund within the time limit of 14 days, and only if you haven't played the game for more than 2 hours**.

Comment: Similar to the [community Wiki answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/395998/163757) on [How are the recommended system specs determined on Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/325367/how-are-the-recommended-system-specs-determined-on-steam).  This truly is probably the best option to really get an idea of how a game may handle on ones hardware.